# How to do cumulative sum row wise?

Tags: r

```
X3            X4            X5            X6            X7            X8            X9
-63.2929      -64.9519      -65.9586      -65.2485      -63.3387      -56.749       -51.7419
-68.7098      -70.2028      -71.329       -70.5252      -68.7843      -63.0799      -58.7491
58.3993       -60.0864      -60.7925      -59.6933      -57.2357      49.8444       44.1056
-57.8334      59.6063       60.3079       -59.1852      -56.6365      -49.2706      -43.5538
-37.6082      -39.6347      -39.6647      38.4396       34.9498       -26.6984      -21.9614
37.2886       39.0565       -38.8722      -37.5427      -33.969       25.9074       21.7712
-61.972       -63.0513      63.5082       -62.2337      59.7711       -54.2189      -51.6613
-60.5783      -61.6254      -61.9812      -60.6696      58.066        -52.4656      -49.9653
```

From above matrix I want to locate a cell with maximum and minimum cell value column wise and then do cumulative sum of every two neighbor’s row wise. For example; for column 1 the minimum is -68.70 (identify the cell) and add (-70.2028 and -71.329) and so on for minimum and same in maximum. How would I do that?

```
data=read.table('test.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')

matrix=data.matrix(data)
```

Comment: It is unclear how the expected output should look like. Could you give us an example?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for? (Warning: hack-y answer using bad coding practices)

```
data = read.table(text = "X3            X4            X5            X6            X7            X8            X9
-63.2929      -64.9519      -65.9586      -65.2485      -63.3387      -56.749       -51.7419
-68.7098      -70.2028      -71.329       -70.5252      -68.7843      -63.0799      -58.7491
58.3993       -60.0864      -60.7925      -59.6933      -57.2357      49.8444       44.1056
-57.8334      59.6063       60.3079       -59.1852      -56.6365      -49.2706      -43.5538
-37.6082      -39.6347      -39.6647      38.4396       34.9498       -26.6984      -21.9614
37.2886       39.0565       -38.8722      -37.5427      -33.969       25.9074       21.7712
-61.972       -63.0513      63.5082       -62.2337      59.7711       -54.2189      -51.6613
-60.5783      -61.6254      -61.9812      -60.6696      58.066        -52.4656      -49.9653", header = T)

sapply(1:(ncol(data)-2), function(x) {c(sum(data[c(which.min(data[,x])),x:(x+2)]),
                                        sum(data[c(which.max(data[,x])),x:(x+2)]))})

          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] -210.2416 -212.057 -210.6385 -202.3894 -190.6133
[2,]  -62.4796   60.729   61.0456   46.6910  -46.1091
```

First row min, second row max.

Comment: This looks right, but is it possible that after finding the minimum and maximum in the column, do running sum (cumulative sum) row wise regardless of negative or positive sign?

Answer (score 0):

```
minsum <- c()
maxsum <- c()

temp <- matrix(sample(c(-1,1),replace=T)*70*runif(70), ncol=7)
for(i in 1:(ncol(temp)-2)){
   tmin <- which.min(temp[,i])
   tmax <- which.max(temp[,i])

   minsum <- c(minsum, temp[tmin,i+1] +  temp[tmin,i + 2] )
   maxsum <- c(maxsum, temp[tmax,i+1] +  temp[tmax,i + 2] )
  }
```

Comment: If you know how long the resulting vector will be (which you do here), the `for` loop will be much faster if you allocate the memory first (instead of building a vector with `x <- c()`). Meaning that since `which.*` produces integers, initializing with `minsum <- maxsum <- vector("integer", ncol(temp)-2))` would be best

Comment: This code subtracts the negative number in the row, for exapmle if minimum is -100 in a column and correspoding row to it is positive ex +20, the out put is -80, is it possible that regardless of the sign, add the rows in a cumulative way upto 7 th colmun row wise

Comment: Yes I am not sure I understand your problem but you could change minsum <- c(minsum, sum(temp[tmin,i+1]:temp[tmin,7) )  and you only want the absolute value do sum( abs( temp[tmin,i+1]:temp[tmin,7) ) )